# How do you include a specific product flavor of a remote dependency in gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Say I'm building and publishing an Android library (to Maven central/JCenter) with two product flavors. For example, I'm building "glide" and "picasso" flavors that provide different dependencies based on which image library you want to use.

Assuming the library has been published to the respective repository, how would the consuming application specify which remote "flavor" they want in their gradle file? Note--the build types are the standard "debug" and "release".

---

Something conceptually like (for the Glide flavor):

`debugCompile ('com.test.library:1.2.0', configuration: 'glideDebug')
releaseCompile ('com.test.library:1.2.0', configuration: 'glideRelease')`

or for Picasso flavor:

`debugCompile ('com.test.library:1.2.0', configuration: 'picassoDebug')
releaseCompile ('com.test.library:1.2.0', configuration: 'picassoRelease')`